# Cygwin reading input piped in from tail -f

Tags: c, windows-7, cygwin, pipe

Using Cygwin on Windows, I wanted to have an audible notification of specific messages in a server's log.  I wrote the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *f = fopen("/dev/stdin", "r");
    char bar=' ';
    if(f==NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    do {
        bar = fgetc(f);
        if((bar=='\n') || (bar=='\r')) {
            printf("\a");
        }
        if(bar!=EOF) {
            printf("%c", bar);
        }
    } while(bar!=EOF);
    fclose(f);
    printf("Done.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I then ran the following command:

```
tail -f serverlog | grep myMessage | ./alerty.exe
```

Sometimes I get notices and sometimes I don't.

My questions are two-fold:
1) What, in my C program, is wrong?  Why can't I consistently read the piped input?  It's piqued my curiosity so I'm desperate to know.

2) How do I accomplish the original goal of making my system beep as specific text appears in a file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. By default stdin/stdout are line-buffered if they are terminal and block-buffered otherwise. That affects not just your program (actually gets will return immediately when something is available and you are printing lines), but **also the grep**. It needs `--line-buffered` flag.
2. Sed should be able to do the work for you. Try just:

   tail -f serverlog | sed -une 's/myMessage/\a&/p'

   (`-u` sets unbuffered—hopefuly cygwin supports it—I am checking on Linux)

Comment: Excuse me, but I am not sure to understand: why not simply use `tail -f serverlog | grep myMessage --line-buffered | ./alerty.exe`? This is: just the O.P. same line, but adding the buffering flag. I have checked my CygWin (updated), and this flag is supported. Is not supposed to order a fflush as `sed` could have done?

Comment: @Sopalajo: I didn't say not to use that. I said DO use it. Exactly as you wrote - `tail -f serverlog | grep --line-buffered myMessage | ./alert.exe` (options should go before positional parameters). The sed is an _alternate_ option.

Answer (score 1):

`stdout` is buffered by default, so the output won't necessarily appear immediately.  Try inserting a `fflush(stdout)` right after your `printf("\a")`.

As Jan mentions, you also may be running into buffering issues on stdin.  `grep` has
a `--line-buffered` option that might help.  (`tail -f` does this on its own, so you shouldn't need to worry about it.)

Comment: Strange. They are actually printing the text itself too and since the output is *line*-buffered, it should flush when the newline is printed.

Comment: @Jan: I think you might be on to something, that maybe it's the upstream buffering that's causing the difficulty as opposed to the output.